# Input stream problem when using std::array

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

When there is no `bool b` in `struct A`, the code works. When `bool b` is there, `ar & mat` gives "input stream error" but registering elements of `std::array` one by one works. What's wrong here?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

struct A
{
    std::array<int, 3> mat;
    bool b;

    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        //ar & mat[0];
        //ar & mat[1];
        //ar & mat[2];
        ar & mat;
        ar & b;
    }
};


int main()
{
    {
        std::string fname = "save.sr";
        std::ofstream ofs(fname);
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        A a;
        oa << a;
    }

    {
        std::string fname = "save.sr";
        std::ifstream ifs(fname);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        A a;
        ia >> a;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"ar & mat gives error"_ please share this error.

Comment: The title didn't let me write "input stream error" and made me to write "input stream problem". Then I forgot to mention the error message in the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see what could be wrong. Then I looked with asan/ubsan and found domain conversion issues: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edee75a22450d9ee

At first I thought maybe there would be a bug in a specific version of Boost[¹]. Then it dawned on me.

There are benign warnings:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -fsanitize=address,undefined -lboost_serialization && ./a.out
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/singleton.hpp:181:12: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const struct extended_type_info_typeid'
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/singleton.hpp:181:12: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const struct oserializer'
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/singleton.hpp:181:12: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const struct extended_type_info_typeid'
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/singleton.hpp:181:12: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const struct iserializer'
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/singleton.hpp:181:12: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const struct extended_type_info_typeid'
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/singleton.hpp:181:12: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const struct extended_type_info_typeid'
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/singleton.hpp:181:12: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const struct oserializer'
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/singleton.hpp:181:12: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const struct extended_type_info_typeid'
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/singleton.hpp:181:12: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const struct iserializer'
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/singleton.hpp:181:12: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const struct extended_type_info_typeid'
```

And then we got the domain error:

> `/usr/local/include/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp:65:50: runtime error: load of value 255, which is not a valid value for type 'bool'`

Notice how it is the `oarchive` that runs into them, and confirm:

```
debug: "22 serialization::archive 17 0 0 0 0 3 -2049146224 32767 -2049145920 1
"
```

Those are... indeterminate values. Not a big problem for a complete integral domain, but it is for bool. So, fix your initialization:

```
struct A {
    std::array<int, 3> mat {};
    bool b {};

    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & mat & b;
    }
};
```

Of course, you can use other styles:

```
std::array<int, 3> mat = {0,0,0};
bool b = false;
```

Or the old-fashioned constructor:

```
std::array<int, 3> mat;
bool b;

A(std::array<int, 3> mat = {}, bool b = {}) : mat(mat), b(b) {}
```

Etc. as long as you make sure you initialize your member data.

**[Fixed On COliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc1fc46bfa92fce5)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/version.hpp>

struct A {
    std::array<int, 3> mat = {0,0,0};
    bool b = false;

    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & mat & b;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
        A a;
        oa << a;
    }

    std::cout << "BOOST_VERSION: " << BOOST_VERSION << "\n";
    std::cout << "debug: " << std::quoted(ss.str()) << "\n";

    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
        A a;
        ia >> a;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
BOOST_VERSION: 107500
debug: "22 serialization::archive 18 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0
"
```

---

[¹] This is what a wild goose chase looks like

- Wandbox Boost 1.73 [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Qd1ghFD9jFLU1V52)
- Wandbox Boost 1.72 [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EQUXKazVQV8A1F5i)
- Wandbox Boost 1.71 [only warnings](https://wandbox.org/permlink/32seFyTbCOWHCTlJ)
- Wandbox Boost 1.70 [same warnings](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JNyvfJitKBdJ6O0A)
- Wandbox Boost 1.69 [same](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wAQEQIn31kg1obNc)
- Wandbox Boost 1.68 [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wAQEQIn31kg1obNc)
- Wandbox Bosot 1.67 [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ctdZ2MoFtD1ViXi5)
- Wanbox Boost 1.66 [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YugcerxKAyX7JPUW)
- Wandbox Boost 1.65.1 [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gw1pB6FpYxvUYghn)
- Wandbox Boost 1.65 [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ztERBXYrsoB7sMfv)
- Wandbox Boost 1.64.0 [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kx9QnzH2bpGMTyLe)
- Wandbox Boost 1.63.0 [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aPj6S82JpW1Pud6r)
- Wandbox Boost 1.62 [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/d2DFtnx0sMfGdu03)
- Wandbox Boost 1.61 [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b5JGh4Clvo1dKWgN)
- Wandbox Boost 1.60 [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zqQ3ZFNko2nz7bUC)

Comment: I have tried to initialize `std::array` but never thought the bool might be the cause of the problem. Thank you.